# Is it possible to read from 64 and 32-bit registry entries in the same installation?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

In my installation I need to check presence of 64-bit entry at first.
And read its value if it is present in 64-bit part of registry.
If entry is absent then I need to try to read this entry from 32-bit registry part(Wow6432Node).

I need to read it directly from wxs file or from custom action on VBScript.
Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you're running a 64bit MSI you can set two AppSearch/RegLocator entries using the style:

```
<Property Id="MY_32BIT_REG">
    <RegistrySearch Id="my32bitreg"
                    Root="HKLM"
                    Key="SOFTWARE\My Company"
                    Name="foo"
                    Type="raw"
                    Win64="no" />
</Property>
<Property Id="MY_64BIT_REG">
    <RegistrySearch Id="my64bitreg"
                    Root="HKLM"
                    Key="SOFTWARE\My Company"
                    Name="foo"
                    Type="raw"
                    Win64="yes" />
</Property>
```

These entries will check the appropriate "HKLM\SOFTWARE\My Company" and "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\My Company" registry hives.

Comment: There is warning "LGHT1076 : ICE80: This 32Bit Package is using 64 bit Locator Type in RegLocator table entry my64bitreg_1" if I use proposed elements in 32bit MSI. But it works. Is it a problem? Or can I just ignore this warning?

Comment: Since you don't need the 64bit registry lookup in your 32bit MSI, I'd just put an 'if' block around the 64bit registry lookup so that it's completely omitted from the 32bit MSI build.